# Extjs upgrade from 5.0 to 5.1 problems

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I have an extjs 5.0 application that don't use the MVC model, ie: all the code is in one file called app.js.
I wanted to upgrade from version 5.0 to 5.1, What is the right way and steps to do so? knowing that I don't use index.html, instead I have a starting page called login.html.

I generated a new app with version 5.1, and modified the path from index.html to login.html, and replaced the ext folders the old with the new, and the build folders as well.

The error message chrome gives me is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

the error occurs in the file FocusManager.js, the line:

```
needListeners[i].addFocusListener();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FocusManager is deprecated in Ext JS 5.1 (although the documentation does not reflect this clearly). Avoid using it.

Comment: Thanks @bhutten you saved me! I just removed the lines with FocusManager.enable(); and it worked fine :-) Thanks a million.